# Vhost on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: apache, virtualhost

VPS running ubuntu 11.10

Using Webmin Created a virtual host [www.site1.com] all working good.

Using Webmin Create another virtual host [www.site2.com] at this point both www.site1.com & www.site2.com are pointing to same www.site2.com even though they have different document root.

Both site1.com and site2.com nameserver are created on same server.

if virtual host www.site2.com is deleted then www.site1.com starts behaving appropriately.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.